# Implication as a proxy for effect

Tags: grammar, word-choice, meaning-in-context, sentence, sentence-patterns

I want to describe that a phenomenon is used to advantage in some methods but for method X it's effects are bad.

So can I write

but it's implication in method X is problematic.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you aiming for 'implementation'? Have you looked up 'implication' in a dictionary (and got a feel for how it's used by reading the example sentences provided)? // Isn't ' ... but its use in method X leads to serious problems' simpler?

Comment: Hi Edwin thank you for the reply. It's not implemented rather it occurs, as a phenomenon, I edited the post. So imlementation is not fitting in. The dictionary says something about "possible effects" e.g., the implications of legislature. Any advice

Comment: ' ... when it arises in method X, it is problematic rather than advantageous' or ' ... though it can actually prove beneficial in other methods, ... ,  this is not the case in method X.'